# How to mock requests using pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

Using pytest I would like to mock the `requests` module that is being used inside my function:

```py
import requests

def get_employee(id):
    resp = requests.get(f'{__BASE_URL}/employee/{id}')
    if resp.status_code == 404:
        return None
    
    return resp.json()
```

I've tried to mock it using this code:

```py
def test_get_employee(mocker):
    get_request_mock = mocker.patch.object(get_employee, "resp")
    print(get_request_mock)
    get_request_mock.status_code = 200
    get_request_mock.json.return_value = {'name': 'awesome-mock'}
    resp = get_employee('random-id')
    assert resp == {'name': 'awesome-mock'}
```

How can I mock `requests` using [mocker](https://pytest-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html)? Is it possible?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use [requests-mock](https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ([PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/requests-mock/)), there is a [fixture](https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pytest.html) for a pytest usage.

For your example:

```py
from correct.package import __BASE_URL
from requests import HTTPError


def test_get_employee(requests_mock):
    test_id = 'random-id'
    requests_mock.get(f'{__BASE_URL}/employee/{test_id}', json= {'name': 'awesome-mock'})
    resp = get_employee('random-id')
    assert resp == {'name': 'awesome-mock'}

def test_absent_employee(requests_mock):
    test_id = 'does_not_exist'
    requests_mock.get(f'{__BASE_URL}/employee/{test_id}', status_code=404)
    with pytest.raises(HTTPError):
        resp = get_employee(test_id)
```

Comment: But how do I mock line `requests.get(f'{__BASE_URL}/employee/{id}')` from function `get_employee(id)`?

Comment: Is possible to return 404?

Comment: Yes. Just add a `status=404` as argument of the `get` function.

Comment: What the hell is correct.package? Can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @Zizzipupp I think `from correct.package import __BASE_URL` is meant as your project's package where the base URL for the resource you're trying to mock is found.

I assume it could be found somewhere in the configuration module.

Answer (score -8):

This may help

```
from unittest import TestCase

import requests
import requests_mock


class TestHTTPRequest(TestCase):
    def test_context_manager(self):
        with requests_mock.Mocker() as mock_request:
            mock_request.get("http://123-fake-api.com", text="Hello!")
            response = requests.get("http://123-fake-api.com")

        assert response.text == "Hello!"
```

Comment: This answer does not use `pytest`, which was explicitly required in the question.